# Rails: joining the 'has_one' and 'belongs_to' association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :user_profile
end

class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

a `User` has one `UserProfile`, and a `UserProfile` belongs to a `User`

The tables structure:

## User

id : integer
name : string
email : string

## UserProfile

id : integer
user_id : integer
bio : string
blog_url : string

Using rails console, I try to get the information of a User by joining both tables:

```
User.joins(:user_profile).includes(:user_profile).where(user_profiles: {user_id: 1})
```

The result on the console screen shows me only the User table, the UserProfile table doesn't show up.

```
 => [#<User id: 1, name: "Alan", email:"alan@example.com">]
```

The SQL statement that appeared on the console screen (the SELECT "users"."id" bla bla...) seems right, since when I copy and paste it to SQLite browser and execute the command, it shows me the result as I expected.

```
|id| name | email            | id | user_id | bio         | blog_url         | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1 | Alan | alan@example.com | 1  | 1       | lorem ipsum | alan.example.com |
```

So I found two different results here.

What might cause these tables not joining on my console?

Answer (score 0):

what you see in console:

```
=> [#<User id: 1, name: "Alan", email:"alan@example.com">]
```

is a string **representation** of a User object, default representation does not include loaded associations(imagine you had million other objects associated with that user - you wouldn't be able to get the thing rendered at all)

to access user profile from user object you have a convenient `#user_profile` method:

```
p user.user_profile
```

to be sure that you're actually fetching this thing from memory and not revisiting database(which is what you are using .include() for) you can tail log/development.log and see that there are no `SELECT * FROM user_profiles` queries at the time when you access user_profile object

also you don't need both `.joins()` and `.includes()`. usually `.includes()` does all you need.

Comment: Understood. So when I need to display a value from the associated object, I may have to use something like `user.user_profile.blog_url`.

Comment: exactly. it's separate objects that have different set of attributes that are exposed via respective methods on those objects.